# Writting a matrix as a product of elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem:
Write the following matrix as a product of elementary matrices:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix} $$

Answer:

First note that since the determinate of this matrix is non-zero we can
write it as a product of elementary matrices. To do this, we use row-operations
to reduce the matrix to the identity matrix. Call the original matrix $M$.
\begin{align*} 
M \sim  \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 \\
 0 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
M \sim  \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
M \sim  \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
The first row operation was $R2 = -3R1 + R2$. The second row operation
was $R2 = -\frac{1}{4}R2$. The third row operation was $R1 = R1 - 3R2$.
Am I right so far? I am not sure how to finish it?
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 -3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Am I right?

Comment: *Am I right?* well, perform the multiplications and see if you get the original matrix back.

Comment: @CroCo I multiplied it out and I got the  wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elementary matrices are
\begin{align*}
R_2&\rightarrow R_2-3R_1 &\implies E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ -3& 1\end{bmatrix} \\
R_2&\rightarrow -\frac{R_2}{2} &\implies E_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0& -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} \\
R_1&\rightarrow R_1-2R_2 &\implies E_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2 \\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

We get
$$
E_3E_2E_1 A = I. 
$$
Note that $A=(E_3E_2E_1)^{-1}$.

Comment: I do not understand where you got E2 from.

Comment: @bob you messed up early in the problem. If your original version of $M$   is correct,   the next version is $E_1 M$  which is $$  \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 2 \\ 
0 & -2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$